# How do I access a test name from the config file?

Tags: report, config, playwright

I want to do the reverse of this: [How do I access playwright test runner project info in a test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68103235/how-do-i-access-playwright-test-runner-project-info-in-a-test).

Something like use testInfo.title in playwright.config.ts

I used the following in my playwright.config.ts with `testInfo` and `return testInfo;` at the end of my spec file

```
outputFolder: `reportLocation/${testInfo.title}`
```

Comment: What problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Can you accept if the answer helped, or continue with follow up qusstions? This will help anyone who comes across this question

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't.

Playwright "reads" test config options first before any test runs, meaning test name is not a known entity.

The opposite is possible as you linked above.

If you wanted to change the outputDir, you could group tests into multiple projects and have a differnet outputDir for each group of tests. Maybe this will be suitable for your case.